# Alternativa a .replace() para que no genere error en funcion con llaves

Tags: javascript, array, str-replace

Estoy creando una funcion que tome un arreglo anidado y lo devuelva en un arreglo unidimensional, el problema es que no puedo hacerlo andar para casos en los que las llaves {} sean un elemento del arreglo, ya que la funcion .replace al detectar lasl laves, me devuelve "object". Que alternativas tengo para este caso?

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
var str= arr.join().replace(/,/g,""); 
  //.replace no anda me cambia los {} 
var newArr= str.split("");
  
var lastArr=[];  
  for(var x=0;x<str.length;x++){
 
    if(isNaN(str.charAt(x))===false){
      lastArr[x]=parseInt(str.charAt(x));
    }else{
      lastArr[x]=str.charAt(x);
    }
     
    
  }
  
  
  return lastArr;
}

console.log(steamrollArray([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]));
```

Comment: ¿Cuál sería el resultado esperado si se encuentra con un objeto?

Comment: El tema es que no le estás pasando llaves, sino que **le estás pasando un objeto**. Si quisieras pasarle un string con llaves: `console.log(steamrollArray([1, "{}", [3, [[4]]]]));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra posible solución (que si no me equivoco hace algo parecido a lo que he puesto en la otra respuesta, aunque de una forma más larga) sería cambiar la función para que haga lo siguiente:

1. Crear un array auxiliar vacío
2. Comprobar si el parámetro es un array; si sí es un array:

   1. Atravesarlo en un bucle
   2. Llamando a la función de manera recursiva para cada elemento
   3. Y concatenando el resultado al array del paso 1
3. , si no lo es:

   1. Devolver un array con el elemento
4. Devolver el array auxiliar del paso 1.

El código sería así:

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  
  var aux = [];

  if (arr.constructor === Array) {
    for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
      aux = aux.concat(steamrollArray(arr[x]));
    }
  } else {
    return [arr];
  }

  return aux;
}

console.log(steamrollArray([1, {a:1}, [3, [[4]]]]));
```

Comment: Esta fue la solucion con la que mas razone' porque es la mas parecida a mi forma de resolverlo, pero no entiendo del todo como funciona lo que esta dentro de los parentesis del if:

`if(arr.constructor === Array){}`

Podrias explicarme como es que funciona?

Comment: @victor.ja Claro. El `if` lo que hace es comprobar si el elemento es un array (comprobado si el constructor es el de un Array); si lo es, tenemos que llamar recursivamente a la función para cade elemento del array (para eliminar los arrays anidados); si no es un array, simplemente devolvemos el elemento porque no hace falta procesar nada más. Espero haberlo dejado un poco más claro, si no, dímelo e intento explicarme mejor

Answer (score 2):

Si buscas una alternativa a replace, sería hacer un 'falso replace' de la siguiente manera:

```js
String.prototype.falsoReplace=function(str, newstr) {
    return this.split(str).join(newstr);
};

var str="Bienvenido, JavaScript";
str=str.falsoReplace('JavaScript', 'victor.ja');
alert(str);
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Usando ES6, [Slikts pone aquí](http://disq.us/p/19apw84) una solución realmente corta para hacer lo que buscas:

```
const flattenDeep = x => Array.isArray(x) ? [].concat(...x.map(flattenDeep)) : x
```

que funciona de maravilla con el array que compartes:

```js
const steamrollArray = x => Array.isArray(x) ? [].concat(...x.map(steamrollArray)) : x;

console.log(steamrollArray([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]));
```